# Find the sum of Fibonacci Series

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I have given a `Set A` i have to find the sum of Fibonacci Sum of All the Subset of `A`
`Fibonacci(X)` - Is the Xth Element of Fibonacci Series
For EX  `A ={1,2,3}`

Fibonacci(1) + Fibonacci(2) + Fibonacci(3) + Fibonacci(1+2) + Fibonacci(2+3) + Fibonacci(1+3) + Fibonacci(1+2+3) 
1+1+2+5+3+8=20

Is there any way i can find the sum without generating the subset.
Since I find the Sum of all subset easily 
i.e. `Sum of All Subset- (1+2+3)*(pow(2,length of set-1))`

Comment: This appears to be related to an active competition:  https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/FIBQ

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is part of an active competition https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/FIBQ

Comment: @lulu me too man. This is cheat! I was finding a google term and got the exact question!

Comment: @SahilArora: Can you tell us when the competition ends? Otherwise it is difficult to manage it.

Comment: You can use the relation $\sum_{k=1}^n F_k=F_{n+2}-1$ to find the sum of consecutive fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula for Fibonacci numbers:
$$ F_n = \frac{\phi^n - \hat\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}}
$$
where $\phi = (1 + \sqrt 5)/2,\hat\phi = (1 - \sqrt 5)/2$ are roots of the equation $x^2 = x + 1$.

To calculate $F_1 + F_2 + F_3$,
$$F_1 + F_2 + F_3 = \frac{\phi - \hat\phi}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{\phi^2 - \hat\phi^2}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{\phi^3 - \hat\phi^3}{\sqrt{5}}
$$

Comment: still not very clear could you explain it with the above example...

Comment: @vxvx Is this OK?

Comment: @HenryW. This is part of an active competition. https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/FIBQ